# Theming user-profile

Tags: 7, theming

I am on Drupal 7. Hi, I have installed the Devel module and I am using it to help me theme the user-profile.tpl.php. I want to show the e-mail information only when the user looking into the user info page is the own user.

I am checking the currently logged in user with $user->uid.

Now I want to get the uid corresponding to the current user page to evaluate if they are the same so that I can print the e-mail. When I go to the Devel  interface, it shows me the information I need on the Load area, when expanding the stdClass information.

How can I use these attributes on the stdClass? I was expecting to do something more or less like $somethinghere->uid to grab the current page user uid, but my trial-and-error process isn't working, I have tried everything... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get the account of the current page via

```
$account = menu_get_object('user');
```

and then check

```
if ($account->uid == $user->uid)
```

menu_get_object will grab the loaded object based on the url